# OmniStudio FlexCard not compiling into an LWC upon activation

Tags: omnistudio

Does anyone know why a FlexCard won’t compile into an LWC when activating it? I have Managed Package Runtime enabled under OmniStudio Settings so I can't figure out why this is happening.